# create a dataframe for multiple line plot for ggplot R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, aggregate

This question is about arranging data for a [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) line plot. I have been doing this manually with [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and I want to work out a way to do this using [r](/questions/tagged/r).

I have reviewed this post which is similar
[Arrange dataframe format for ggplot - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179207/arrange-dataframe-format-for-ggplot-r)

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: dataset]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwGN7.png)

I want to convert it to a [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) that is divided into the groups (N,A,G) and into age brackets and the proportion per `age_group`.

An example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: what I would like to create for ggplot]

Appreciate your help.

Data:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:10, Age = c(9L, 16L, 12L, 13L, 29L, 24L, 
23L, 24L, 16L, 40L), Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), Age_group = 
c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L), N = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), G = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: @akrun have added data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I transform a data frame and make multiple line graphs in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60909937/how-do-i-transform-a-data-frame-and-make-multiple-line-graphs-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pivot to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then create a grouping variable with `cut` on the 'Age' and get the `sum` of 'n' and 'proportion'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = N:G, names_to = 'group', values_to = 'n') %>%
     group_by(Age_group_new = cut(Age, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, seq(10, 70, by = 10), 100, Inf)), group) %>%
     summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
     group_by(Age_group_new) %>% 
     mutate(proportion = n/sum(n),
         proportion = replace(proportion, is.nan(proportion), 0))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun. I have tried downloading tidyr and tidyverse but I still get this error:  could not find function "pivot_longer"

Comment: @sar doo you hhave a tidyr version  older than 1.0.0.  It is a new function.  If your versioin is older, you can  use `gather(group, n, N:G) %>%`

Comment: This creates a dataframe within the first dataframe (ie with lines for each ID - my dataset went from  779 rows to 20254 rows). Is it possible to summarise? ie. for each of columsn (N,A,G) have the age groups by decades (eight rows per group)?

Comment: @sar, in that case, just replace `mutate` with `summarise`

Comment: Thats better @akrun. There are still two minor things: there is an additional row (-Inf,0] for each of the groups. The proportion also doesn't calculate - only NaN for zeros and 1 for any numbers. The proportion needs to be of the sum of all the positive results in the age group

Comment: @sar It would be related to the `breaks`  I added as I was not sure which all levels are needed.  You can either modify the `breaks` statement or remove that row with `filter` afterwards

Comment: @sar do you want to replace the `NaN`.  It is crreate only because you are dividing with 0 in the numerator

Comment: I will want to plot the NaN as zero

Comment: @sar I added the `replace` at the end

Comment: @sar I guess you wanted `summarise(n = sum(n), proportion = n/sum(.$n))` instead of `sum(n)`

Comment: the proportion needs to be the n/sum of all positives in that age bracket. Ie. for age bracket 11-20 there are 4 positives, 3 N and 1 G, so the proportions would be 0.75 and 0.25

Comment: minor thing. How do I get the filter to remove the inf row? it tried this     df %>% filter((-Inf,0],Age_group_new )

Comment: @sar  %>% filter(!str_detect(Age_group, "Inf"))`

Comment: is there a way to change the Age_group_new character to 10-20, or (10,20), rather than (10,20] ?

Comment: @sar Either, we can use `group_by(Age_group_new = gsub("\\(|\\)", "", Age_group_new))`  or change with the `labels` argument in `cut`

Comment: thanks very much. When I try this I get    Error in gsub("\\(|\\)", "", Age_group_new) : 
  object 'Age_group_new' not found

Comment: @sar sorry it should be wrapped i.e. `mutate(Age_group_new = cut(Age, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, seq(10, 70, by = 10), 100, Inf)) %>% group_by(Age_group_new = gsub("\\(|\\)", "", Age_group_new))`

Comment: hmm, perhaps it is best to leave well alone, as when I do this I get another error    Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor". I think I will leave it as it was with the (0-10].

Comment: @sar `df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = N:G, names_to = 'group', values_to = 'n') %>%
      group_by(Age_group_new = gsub("\\(|\\]", "", cut(Age, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, seq(10, 70, by = 10), 100, Inf))), group) %>%
      summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
      group_by(Age_group_new) %>% 
      mutate(proportion = n/sum(n),
          proportion = replace(proportion, is.nan(proportion), 0))` works for me

Comment: perfecto! that is great!